# ERROR: FPM initialization failed (php-fpm)

Tags: nginx, vagrant, homebrew, php

I've been trying to get a vagrant virtual box running on my machine, but when I access a local server it throws a 502 Bad Gateway - nginx error.

After doing some reading I think I've traced it to an issue with php-fpm. So far I've tried reinstalling php-fpm (via homebrew), making sure its been added to $PATH, brew tap my php install source, and restarting it. Still getting the same error.

Example:

```
$ which php-fpm
/usr/sbin/php-fpm
$ /usr/sbin/php-fpm --test
```

Output:

```
$ ERROR: failed to open configuration file '/private/etc/php-fpm.conf': No such file or directory (2)
$ ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/private/etc/php-fpm.conf'
$ ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

or:

```
$ php-fpm -c /usr/sbin/php-fpm
PHP:  parse error in /usr/sbin/php-fpm on line 1
```

Edit: I don't seem to have a php-fpm.conf file anywhere. Guess I need to create this?

I'm on a mac running Mavericks.

Comment: and you are 100% sure that file exists in that folder structure?

Comment: by file you mean php-fpm.conf?

Comment: Yes i mean the /private/etc/php-fpm.conf file

Comment: doesn't look like php.fpm.conf file exists anywhere, on that path or otherwise. So looks like I need to create one: http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php

Comment: sudo cp /private/etc/php-fpm.conf.default /private/etc/php-fpm.conf